# Deciding on a Test Technique - ISTQB (Foundation Level)

Tags: istqb

I have found the following question in a Sample Paper for ISTQB Foundation Level available online.

16. What is the important criterion in deciding what testing technique to use?

    - a. how well you know a particular technique
    - b. the objective of the test
    - c. how appropriate the technique is for testing the application
    - d. whether there is a tool to support the technique

Answer given by them is :

```
- b. the objective of the test
```

But I feel that **answer C is also correct** because the techniques you choose must be appropriate for the application too. For example, if you are testing a dropdown which allows you to select if you are male or female and save it (Let us assume that nothing in the application depends on your choice), there is no point using Decision Table Technique to test the dropdown.

Can anyone justify **why 'only the Answer B' is correct**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objective of the test is to only test two states this could lead to the appropriate testing technique, since it limits the technique's that are useful.

To quote from the [Professional Testers Manifesto](http://www.professionaltestersmanifesto.org/):

> That testing benefits from diversity and not homogeneity: that testing
>   is not a profession that can be standardized but instead needs to
>   remain an intellectual professional activity.

I think probably both answers are fine. Keep in mind ISTQB is there to get you certified not to teach you good testing by any means. Learn to pass the exam. Let the world teach you how to test.

Comment: Amen sir! " Learn to pass the exam. Let the world teach you how to test"

Answer (score 3):

"The Objective of the test" is the answer.

As your objective will decide what you want to achieve from the Test. And by foreseeing your end result, you decide which technique you want to use.

For example, At different stages of software development cycle(or test cycle) you choose different technique to perform the test. You can't decide the technique by "how appropriate the technique is for testing the application", it can be best technique but other constrains might not allow you to choose/use it.

And in ISTQB exams, you will feel each option is the answer, but we need to choose the best suitable one. I am completely agree with what Niels said above.